# Should I aim to add a class/id to everything, or use other selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm never sure what the best (most efficient) way to select an element is.

Lets say I have the following layout (extremely simple example)

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

1. I want to select my unordered list (ensuring I don't affect any other UL's throughout my site), should I do `#navigation ul {}` or assign a class to the UL?
2. I want to select my list items, again ensuring I only affect those. Should I do `navigation ul li{}` or assign a class?
3. And finally, If I want to select my first link and style it, should I do `#navigation ul li:first-child {}` or assign a class?

I appreciate these questions are pretty much the same, but I'm curious when you should use a class and when not to.

Comment: For 1, 2, and 3 - If there are any other `ul`'s in your `navigation` div how are you going to differentiate them? It's a very simple answer and only you can answer it. It all depends on your layout / the items on your page. If you can use a class / id do so, it makes your task of referencing items much more compact and readable to others.

Comment: Your question title is... misphrased. Classes and ids _are_ selectors, so really, it would be better to say "Should I aim to add a class/id to everything, or use _other_ selectors." I'm going to edit it so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no hard and fast answer here.

A general rule of thumb *might* be to use classes when you want to group certain elements together, treat them the same and using a class is the only means of doing it.

In your last example for instance, there is strictly no need for a class.

But, using a class in example 3 will result in better performance, as the browser will located the relevant items quicker. Traded off against this is a slight reduction in code-legibility..
If you have class names on everything then it becomes harder to read the rest of the markup.

In short, in what you have shown above, what you have written is fine imo.

You should read [this](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) article though which covers selector efficiency.

Basically the order of efficiency is as follows:

```
ID, e.g. #header
Class, e.g. .promo
Type, e.g. div
Adjacent sibling, e.g. h2 + p
Child, e.g. li > ul
Descendant, e.g. ul a
Universal, i.e. *
Attribute, e.g. [type="text"]
Pseudo-classes/-elements, e.g. a:hover
```

The performance difference between classes and Id's is normally irrelevant.

Going further down the list though, things slow down considerably.

This isn't an argument to add classes and id's everywhere - it just allows you to judge the trade-off between performance and maintainability.

Comment: +1, Nice answer. Thanks for the link. Some of that I knew, but it was a good discussion. The only thing I would perhaps disagree on is the irrelevancy of `id` vs. `class`. I would think that the speed difference might be more noticable between those if a `class` is used on a lot of items (picture 10,000 items with a `class` set, versus the still unique `id`). However, admittedly, this would be a special circumstance, and both your and the article's point about irrelevancy is in most cases probably true.

Answer (score 0):

#id should be unique and class shouldn't.

so if you need to add some JS - you need #id, if you just want to style different elements, .class is fine.

Comment: He is not asking for what the difference between an ID and a class is.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it really depends on how complex the structure underneath the #navigation element will end up being. Referencing everything using the #navigation element is probably OK if it is a simple structure like you have shown, but to me if it is more complex or will have different ul, li elements that will need different behaviors then I would id/class the nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript usage, I think to is more faster than use native selector, and no class or id.

For more details, I think just testing this theory with complex code ( for see the different time ).

Don't forget the javaScript's faster depends to your browser.

For CSS, a good article is [here](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/) for more details.